# When I said I used sugar in coffee, I was asked, "For tea, too?"

Tags: riddle, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

My road is filled with answers, and my body has the hints, but it is in my head where the question sits. My shoes are brand new, hence their tags.

Can you end my walk down this road with an answer-question?

Comment: What is the meaning of life?

Comment: @Goinghamateur Among other things ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> « What do you get if you multiply six by nine? »

> This is the question that leads to 42, the [Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#The_Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything_is_42); 42 being encoded into the title (« For tea too »)

My road is filled with answers,...

> This site, precisely, is filled with answers

... and my body has the hints,...

> Questions here may have hints

... but it is in my head where the question sits...

> The actual question (puzzle) lies in the head of each page

... My shoes are brand new, hence their tags...

> Questions here usually have tags in their footer

... Can you end my walk down this road...

> This walk is reminiscent of "How many roads must a man walk down?", a lyric from Bob Dylan's song "Blowin' in the Wind" which was suggested to be the question leading to the answer "42", in The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy.

... with an answer-question?

> A question is awaited as an answer

Comment: A little addition: typically, the question entails what the answer is. In this case, the answer entails what the question is, as well. The scene where supercomputer says "42" is the answer, they also say that to know what the answer means, they must know the question. So, you have an answer without a question, allowing you to go backwards from it to the question.

Comment: @tmpearce In the base 10 that we, humble humans, use every day, yes, the math is incorrect. See the WP article I linked in my answer :-)